# Azure Notification Hub vs Pusher

Tags: pusher, azure-notificationhub

I'm currently using Pusher for push notifications to my web app's front end (web).

I just learned about Azure's Notification Hub.

Could I use Azure Notification Hub the same way I do Pusher? I only ever see MS talking about Notification Hub in the context of mobile apps.

Answer (score 1):

Azure's Notification Hub is targeted to mobile platforms.
So I don't think it's suitable for your web app.
You can switch to https://socket.io

Comment: What does Socket.io have to do with anything??